# Speed equation - why are the constants negative?

Tags: kinematics, calculus

I want to show that the the equation $a = \dfrac{dv}{dt}$ leads to $v=v_0 + at$:
$$a = \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$
$$a\, dt = dv$$
$$a\int dt = \int dv$$
Why do we chose a negative sign for the constants here? This leads to:
$$a(t-t_0)=v-v_0$$
assuming $t_0=0$
$$a\ t=v-v_0$$
$$v=v_0 + at$$

**Edit**: @Tushar pointed out I chose the wrong sign for the constants, thus I updated the question to reflect this. I intuitively understand it must be like this. Still, I don't understand what is the reason for it.

Comment: You have done mistake at step $$a(t+t_0)=v+v_0$$ you didn't put the limits correctly, it should be $$a(t-t_0)=v-v_0$$

Comment: @Tushar: I understand that the constant can have either sign. Also, a negative sign makes more sense here. I agree it should be $-t_0$ and $-v_0$. But what is the justification for doing so?

Comment: @KooDooMoo That sign is coming from integration:
                            $\int f(x).dx = F(x) + c$, then
                            $\int_a^bf(x).dx = F(b) - F(a)$

Comment: @KooDooMoo If you want the justification for doing so then you are probably on the wrong site because you are indirectly seeking the derivations of the formulae of integration which should be asked on mathematics website of stack exchange network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not choosing any signs for constants, they naturally come out of integration,

$$
a = \frac{\mathscr{d}v}{\mathscr{d}t} \tag{1}
$$

Integrating on both sides with appropriate limits ($t:t_i \rightarrow t_f$, $v:v_i \rightarrow v_f$),

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{t_i}^{t_f} a \, \mathscr{d}t &= \int_{v_i}^{v_f}\mathscr{d}v \\
a \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \mathscr{d}t &= \int_{v_i}^{v_f}\mathscr{d}v \\
a \, \big[ t \big]_{t_i}^{t_f} &= \big[ v \big]_{v_i}^{v_f} \\
a (t_f - t_i) &= (v_f - v_i) \\
v_f &= v_i + a(t_f -t_i) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$

Based on boundary conditions, you can modify Eq(2). I would recommend you to look at [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).